# Operation not permitted error

Tags: ubuntu, cp

I'm trying to copy a file in which i'm facing below error.

```
$ cp encryptionkey.img ~/Desktop/
cp: cannot open 'encryptionkey.img' for reading: Operation not permitted.
```

I do't know why cp is not permitted for this file

Answer (score 0):

You need elevated/root privileges. try `sudo cp encryptionkey.img ~/Desktop/`

Comment: Sudo also doesn't work

Comment: try sudo chmod 755 encryptionkey.img

then cp encryptionkey.img ~/Desktop/

Comment: even after chmod also cp doesn't work..Idk why

Comment: `Operation not permitted` (`EPERM`) is not the same thing as `Permission denied` (`EACCES`).  The latter is the error you get when certain action is denied due to the lack of ordinary permission ("ugorwx"). An *example* that causes the former is when the file is marked as immutable (`chattr +i`). I myself haven't bumped into `EPERM` for reading any file though. (Well at least I don't recall I had such an experience.) So no idea what's actually the case here.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Finally i found a solution to it.It was my antivirus which was blocking read on that file.After stopping it for  a  while, everything worked